# Staying up late to say night prayer

Tags: salat

Is one who intends to say night prayer encouraged  to **first sleep** for some time and **then wake up** to offer his/her night prayer, or can they simply stay up late till the last third of the night arrives?

Comment: The first one: sleep → wake up → pray.

Comment: See also: "[Praying Tahajjud in the summers. Can anyone give me some advice please](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24457/9123)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Tahajjud” is derived from “Hujud”, meaning sleep. Sleep is necessary, even if you sleep for a few minutes. If you offer prayer without sleep that prayer will be consider as nawafil and some school of thoughts also consider prayer without sleep as Tahajudd.

Comment: If this answer is wrong then please correct me?

Comment: I think there must be some element of truth to your answer. Actually Arabic is not my mother language, but I happened to come across the exact meaning of _tahajjud_ on the internet yesterday, which seemingly implied two opposite implications, i.e. sleeping and praying (or something along these lines). This is helpful to me and I'll upvote it once I'll earn more scores! thank you

Comment: @Itsme Thanks for confirmation because i also realized my answer is bit unclear and we have to very careful on religion discussion and one thing i clearly say that whether you sleep or not for midnight prayer you will get much blessings from Allah because Allah likes midnight prayer.